# Flutter - firebase_dynamic_links : Failed to notify dependency resolution listener

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am getting the below error while running app after adding `firebase_dynamic_links` dependency.

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
> > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.0,16.0.0]], but
> resolves to 16.0.3. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
> tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> > The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.1.1,16.1.1]], but
> resolves to 16.2.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
> tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
> 
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 
> BUILD FAILED in 2s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
> failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried changing version of `firebase_dynamic_links` to all available version with no luck.

I couldn't figure out what to do after running `./gradlew :app:dependencies` as well.

Below is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: socially360
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2
  json_annotation: ^2.1.0
  built_value: ^6.3.2
  built_collection: ^4.2.0
  rxdart: ^0.21.0
  url_launcher: ^5.0.2
  intl: ^0.15.8
  firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
  advanced_share: 0.1.0
  share: 0.6.1
  firebase_dynamic_links: 0.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  built_value_generator: ^6.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the below line from **app\build.gradle** file solved the issue for me.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```